# Firebase does not Verify IdToken

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When the backend is called by passing the idToken used on the client (Web, Android and Postman) an exception occurs:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1581447909769,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Authentication Failed: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Firebase ID token has expired or is not yet valid. Get a fresh ID token and try again. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.",
    "path": "/api/references"
}
```

The backend is **able to access firebase resources**, for example:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser("SOME_ID")
```

The error **only occurs when verifying** a token:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(authenticationToken.getToken());
```

The settings:

```
  @Bean
    public FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth() throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = FirebaseAuthConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("solicite-service-auth.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-project-auth.firebaseio.com")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

jwt.io

```
{
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/my-project-auth",
  "aud": "my-project-auth",
  "auth_time": 1581453521,
  "user_id": "SOME_USER_ID",
  "sub": "SOME_USER_ID",
  "iat": 1581453521,
  "exp": 1581457121,
  "email": "teste@teste.com",
  "email_verified": false,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "email": [
        "teste@teste.com"
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "password"
  }
}
```

I have already deleted and recreated the service account and projects. As I can access Firebase through the SDK I believe it is correctly configured.

Authentication worked a few months ago.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the ID token that you passed is invalid.  There's not enough information here to know why that is. You're going to have to do some debugging and figure out why the value doesn't validate as you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson At first I thought the problem was with the clients. That's when I started using postman for make requests. I make the request REST API based on the return json I retrieve the idToken and make a request passing it to the backend. My backend only validates if there is an authentication token, if it exists it tries to validate in Firebase. I've been debugging into the library and I still can't find the error. My hope is for someone to see and say that it is a simple error, that I forgot to configure something on the firebase console.

Comment: It says your token is either expired or not yet valid (most likely the former). If you're certain the ID token is not expired, make sure your servers clock is synchronized.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka 
the problem was really the server clock and the clock on my desktop. I'm in Brazil and this year we didn't have summer time. The point was that my machine was on time, but the firebase was incorrect. I had to add an hour to my computer and the token started working, after a few days the firebase took off daylight saving time and everything is correct now.